# Python TypeError from the coad that I copy from another .py file

Tags: typeerror

Here is the code that I copy from another .py file and I got a TypeError

```
#coding:utf-8
import serial
import sys
import time
import logging

class TestRemoteControl(object):
    def __init__(self,com):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(com,115200)
        self.ser.bytesize = 8
        self.ser.stopbits = 1
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)-25s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        self.ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        self.ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.fh = logging.FileHandler('Test.txt')
        self.fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.fh.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        self.ch.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.ch)
        self.logger.addFilter(self.fh)

    def start_esc(self):
        self.logger.info("开启电机")
        self.ser.write("####1")

    def stop_esc(self):
        self.logger.info("关闭电机")
        self.ser.write("####1")
        time.sleep(0.4)
        self.ser.write("####1")
        time.sleep(0.4)
        self.ser.write("####1")
        time.sleep(0.4)


    def speed_up(self):
        self.logger.info("电机加速")
        self.ser.write("####3")

    def speed_down(self):
        self.logger.info("电机减速")
        self.ser.write("####2")

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
        format = '%(asctime)s %(filename)s[line:%(lineno)d] %(levelname)s %(message)s',
        datefmt = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S',
        filename = 'myapp.log',
        filemode = 'w')

    print("please enter com num:")
    a = raw_input()

    temp_com = "com"+a
    test_RC = TestRemoteControl(temp_com)
    count = 1
    max_count = int(raw_input('Please enter on-off counts'))
    while count < max_count:
        test_RC.start_esc()
        # time.sleep(10)
        # test_RC.speed_up()
        time.sleep(2)
        test_RC.stop_esc()
        print "complete ",count," times "
        time.sleep(1)
        count += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the error, I don't kown why. Help me please.
TypeError:

> unbound method **init**() must be called with TestRemoteControl instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Answer (score 0):

This code is OK.All the problem is the IDE "pycharm" that I can only run the unittest because I used the name "TestRemoteControl"